# Why doesn't Dataloader use specified 10k batch size when Bulk API is selected?

Tags: batch, data-loader, bulk-api, insert, data-migration

I have this sample CSV file containing 10,000 records (with 33 columns) I'd like to import it via **Dataloader** into Case object at my sandbox environment.

I tried using these settings below with **Bulk-api in parallel mode** thinking that insertion will be done in an instant following this statement : ["The maximum value is 10,000 if the Use Bulk API option is selected."](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=configuring_the_data_loader.htm&language=en_US&type=0) But instead, the insertion proceeded with a batch of 200 at time, overall taking ~15mins to finish the job.

[image: My Dataloader settings]

Disclaimer:

1. Dataloader version for Windows used = 39.0.0
2. My internet connection is pretty good (>30Mbps, ping 4ms).
3. Total Processing Time (ms)  906008
4. API Active Processing Time (ms) 741457
5. Apex Processing Time (ms)   8898917

***Question : Why did the batch size cap at 200 and not 10k as advertised? And how do I get it to insert 10k at a time using bulk-api? (Ultimately, how do I get it to run significantly faster?)***

Comment: Did you happen to log out then log back in after you made the change?

Comment: @Eric No ... I just watched the progress bar to completion like watching paint dry. So there was no accidental log out/in issue.

Comment: When you make the change to the settings, log out then log back in ( via data loader) and the new settings should take effect. I have found that without doing that it "sometimes" did not communicate with the new settings

Comment: Did you "logout" first? File -> Logout? If so I am out of ideas

Comment: Yea I tried logging out, closing, re-opening. My settings still stayed the same. This is so freaking weird. Mind sharing with me a 10k sample I can insert to my sandbox to see if its just the problem with my sample?

Comment: Otherwise try different version of dataloader. Sometimes latest versions can be bit buggy.

Comment: @RahulSharma hmm can you suggest which dataloader versions?

Comment: We had recently used v37.0 for bulk load without  any issues. So maybe try 37 or 38

Comment: I just tried with v37 and v38 ... it's still processing at the same slow speed. From looking at the bulk apex jobs I found I have been using just 1 batch of 10000 this whole time! However I'm still wondering why it processes 200 at a time on progress bar. Maybe the mapping for my sample is exponentially complicated which limits my insertion speed...